# Python put output in print of list

Tags: python, if-statement, indexing, nested

Got this exellent coding help from Tom Wojcik https://stackoverflow.com/users/5833429/tom-wojcik

with the code below I find YoY changes and can list those that have consecutive gotten better or worse. It works on my large country list. Everything is good.

But now I'm assigned to do a printout of the Countries, Year and score per year for those that have improved every year.

The code lists in this case two countries that have YoY improvement every year. But how do I get that find_yoy() to print to information from the nested list (lst) instead of just the names?

I've tried to find the indexes of the country name that is output, but it just becomes to complex for me putting that info to something useful.

Do you have any tips or trix on how to approach this?

Code below:

```
lst = [
    ['',2018,2015,2012,2009,2006,2003],
    ["Country1",523,525,527,530,531,532],
    ["Country2",551,548,561,555,547,550],
    ["Country3",545,538,536,534,533,529],
    ["Country4",526,524,515,510,505,500]
]

_, *year_data = lst.pop(0)
countries = lst


def is_decreasing(lst) -> bool:
    last_checked, *rest = lst
    for year_data in rest:
        if year_data < last_checked:
            last_checked = year_data
        else:
            return False
    return True


def is_increasing(lst) -> bool:
    last_checked, *rest = lst
    for year_data in rest:
        if year_data > last_checked:
            last_checked = year_data
        else:
            return False
    return True


def find_yoy():
    increasing_yoy = []
    decreasing_yoy = []

    for country in countries:
        country_name, *country_data = country
        assert len(year_data) == len(country_data)
        sorted_year_data, sorted_country_data = zip(*sorted(zip(year_data, country_data)))

        if is_increasing(sorted_country_data):
            increasing_yoy.append(country_name)
        elif is_decreasing(sorted_country_data):
            decreasing_yoy.append(country_name)

    print("countries with increasing yoy:", ', '.join(increasing_yoy), '.')
    print("countries with decreasing yoy:", ','.join(decreasing_yoy), '.')

find_yoy()
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the quantity values from `lst` corresponding to a country?  For example,  for 'Country1' do you want `[523, 525, 527, 530, 531, 532]` (unless values also need to be ordered by year)?

Comment: Exactly. If the code returns Country1 I'd like to print, ["Country1",523,525,527,530,531,532]. It could be that it returns nothing or many countries and it should handle all of it.

Comment: @IngemarFogelberg--I posted a code example where the function `country_info` returns the data for a country.  Is this what you meant or something else?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Will try to condense more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use list comprehension to get the right row from list (performed in function country_info)

**Code**

```
lst = [
    ['',2018,2015,2012,2009,2006,2003],
    ["Country1",523,525,527,530,531,532],
    ["Country2",551,548,561,555,547,550],
    ["Country3",545,538,536,534,533,529],
    ["Country4",526,524,515,510,505,500]
]

_, *year_data = lst.pop(0)
countries = lst

def is_decreasing(lst) -> bool:
    last_checked, *rest = lst
    for year_data in rest:
        if year_data < last_checked:
            last_checked = year_data
        else:
            return False
    return True

def is_increasing(lst) -> bool:
    last_checked, *rest = lst
    for year_data in rest:
        if year_data > last_checked:
            last_checked = year_data
        else:
            return False
    return True

def find_yoy():
    increasing_yoy = []
    decreasing_yoy = []

    for country in countries:
        country_name, *country_data = country
        assert len(year_data) == len(country_data)
        sorted_year_data, sorted_country_data = zip(*sorted(zip(year_data, country_data)))

        if is_increasing(sorted_country_data):
            increasing_yoy.append(country_name)
        elif is_decreasing(sorted_country_data):
            decreasing_yoy.append(country_name)

    return increasing_yoy, decreasing_yoy
    
def country_info(country, countries):
    ' Get Data for country'
    for l in countries:
        if l[0] == country:
            return l[1:]
        
# list of increasing & decreasing
increasing_yoy, decreasing_yoy = find_yoy()
print("countries with increasing yoy:", ', '.join(increasing_yoy), '.')
print("countries with decreasing yoy:", ','.join(decreasing_yoy), '.')

# Show increasing countries
print("\nIncreasing countries and values")
for country in increasing_yoy:
    data = country_info(country, countries)
    print(f'Country {country} with values {data}')
    
print("\nDecreasing countries and values")
for country in decreasing_yoy:
    data = country_info(country, countries)
    print(f'Country {country} with values {data}')
```

**Output**

```
countries with increasing yoy: Country3, Country4 .
countries with decreasing yoy: Country1 .

Increasing countries and values
Country Country3 with values [545, 538, 536, 534, 533, 529]
Country Country4 with values [526, 524, 515, 510, 505, 500]

Decreasing countries and values
Country Country1 with values [523, 525, 527, 530, 531, 532]
```

Comment: Worked well on the sample data, but I'm getting this error "TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found.

Comment: Trying to edit my post, but it wont work. My actual data is formatted like this:
lst = [
    ['','2018','2015','2012','2009','2006','2003'],
    ['Country1','523','525','527','530','531','532'],
    ['Country2','551','548','561','555','547','550'],
    ['Country3','545','538','536','534','533','529'],
    ['Country4','526','524','515','510','505','500']
]
Tested the code and it runs well. But throws a TyprError on my real data.
More specifically here:
print("countries with increasing yoy:", ', '.join(increasing_yoy), '.')

Comment: Tried from this:
print("countries with increasing yoy:", ', '.join(increasing_yoy), '.')

To this:
print("countries with increasing yoy:", ', '.join(map(str, increasing_yoy)), '.')

And it worked. Many thanks for your help!

Comment: @IngemarFogelberg--I don't see the difference in your formatted data from the comment (i.e. copy/paste comment gives me the same data).  Are you able to post the different data in your post or perhaps some other online source?

Comment: @DarryIG - Strange. It’s like this, single quotes on year, ’2018’ and single quotes on scores, ’515’.

Comment: @IngemarFogelberg--I have single quotes on all the strings.  Perhaps if you shared the code thorough the online websites (i..e JSFiddle, Github, etc. i.e. [code sharing websites](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/top-7-code-sharing-website-for-developers/)